# Inflating layout from withing FrameLayout and adding it to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `layout.xml` which is `FrameLayout` and it has another `FrameLayout` inside.
I have class `Field` subclassing `FrameLayout` that contains logic, background color handling etc.

I want to do something like this:

```
Field f = new Field(width, height, color); //args can be changed if needed.
linearLayout.addView(f);
```

Inside `Field` class in a constructor I do this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_board_field, null);
```

Something is added to `linearLayout` beccause its children count is not 0, but I can't see the red square that `Field` is.
Is there something I do wrong(clearly)?

Comment: Decided to change inflation method to.  
View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_game_board_field, this);

Now something is appearing in layout, but its shape is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this was it.

```
View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_game_board_field, this);
```

Apart from that I had to correct other properties in xml, because I dropped Frament approach and decided to inflate layouts by hand.